# How does this javascript alternate text spinner work

Tags: javascript

This code spins the 3d text alternately clockwise then anticlockwise and then repeats the same and works well. I know it can be easier done in CSS and perhaps it can be more elegantly coded in Javascript. But I particularly want to understand better how this exact code works in Javascript as an exercise to improve my knowledge. I'm looking for someone to very clearly comment the code out explaining how it works please. The current short comments aren't enough to help me understand the code unfortunately.

I already understand how this code works in the sense of it, css 3d transform in the javascript and it uses if and else statements and it uses a global variable 'currentDirection' and 'currentAngle' to handle direction and angle, but what I don't understand is how mathematically the program works, exactly how the sequence of if and else statements and direction and angle changes progress the text to and fro and left and right.

```
var currentAngle = 0;
var currentDirection = 0; // 0 - Increasing, 1 - 
Decreasing

function spin() {
document.getElementById("myDIV");
setInterval(function() {
if(currentDirection == 0) {
  // Allow one complete rotation.
  if(currentAngle < 360) { 
    myDIV.style.transform = "rotate3d(0,1,0.2,"+ 
  currentAngle +"deg)";
    currentAngle += 10;
  } else {
    // Change the direction.
    currentDirection = 1;
    currentAngle -= 10;
    myDIV.style.transform = "rotate3d(0,1,0.2,"+ 
    currentAngle +"deg)";
  }
  } else {
  // Allow one complete rotation.
  if(currentAngle > 0) { //why does this send the text one complete revolution anticlockwise???
    myDIV.style.transform = "rotate3d(0,1,0.2,"+ 
  currentAngle +"deg)";
    currentAngle -= 10;
  } else {
    // Change the direction.
    currentDirection = 0;
    currentAngle += 10;
    myDIV.style.transform = "rotate3d(0,1,0.2,"+ 
    currentAngle +"deg)";
   }
   }
   }, 80);
   }
   spin();
   <div style="text-align:center;">
  <h1 id='myDIV'>my 3d text</h1>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm grateful for the contributions, however they didn't answer the question in the detail I wanted. As with more time, I have worked this out myself, I'm going to answer the question by using more detailed comments in the code below.

```
    var currentAngle = 0; /*declares a global variable*/ 
    var currentDirection = 0; // 0 - Increasing, 1 - 
    Decreasing /*declares a global variable */

     function spin() { /*beings a function called spin*/
     document.getElementById("myDIV"); /*collect the element myDIV into the spin function ready to use*/
    setInterval(function() { /*set the animation timing interval between repeats of the animation */
    if(currentDirection == 0) { /*if it's true that the variable currentDirection is set at 0, run the next if statement */
    /* Allow one complete rotation.*/
    if(currentAngle < 360) { /*if it's also true that the currentAngle is less than 360 degrees run the code in the curly braces repeatedly, until the 3d text reaches rotated clockwise 360 degrees, this uses css rotate3d*/
    myDIV.style.transform = "rotate3d(0,1,0.2,"+ 
     currentAngle +"deg)";
    currentAngle += 10;
     } else {
    /*Change the direction of the 3d text to anticlockwise, once the text reaches one full revolution or at 360 degrees.*/
    currentDirection = 1;
    currentAngle -= 10;
    myDIV.style.transform = "rotate3d(0,1,0.2,"+ 
    currentAngle +"deg)";
    }
    } 

    else {
    /* Allow one complete rotation.
      if(currentAngle > 0) { /*The 3d text had previously 
   rotated 360 degrees, but now to reverse it 360 degrees 
   the program says if the current angle is greater than 0 
   (which it will be because at this point in the program 
   it's at 360 degrees) keep reversing the 3d text in 10 
    degree increments until it reaches 0 degrees */
     myDIV.style.transform = "rotate3d(0,1,0.2,"+ 
     currentAngle +"deg)";
     currentAngle -= 10;
     } else { /*once the program has reached 0degrees, 
    change the direction and change the current angle to 
    clockwise.*/
     /*note, the variable currentDirection is not actually 
    changing the direction in itself, current angle is, 
    currentDirection is merely a variable to help control 
    the flow of the program, almost like what javascript 
    programmers call a flag or a boolean false/true */
     currentDirection = 0;
     currentAngle += 10;
     myDIV.style.transform = "rotate3d(0,1,0.2,"+ 
     currentAngle +"deg)";
    }
    }
    }, 80); /*80 is the frequency timing how often the 
  animation runs */
    }
    spin(); /*this line sets the function running, it's a 
    function call */

    <div style="text-align:center;">
   <h1 id='myDIV'>my 3d text</h1>
   </div> /* the html div that holds the text */
```

Answer (score 0):

The code works by setting the CSS transform property in javascript around 12 times every second.

To explore this more I recommend checking out [CSS 3D Transforms - W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_3dtransforms.asp),
and maybe combine this with [CSS animations](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp).

```js
var currentAngle = 0;
var currentDirection = 0; // 0 - Increasing, 1 - Decreasing

function spin() {
  // Find the div element
  var myDIV = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  
  // Set interval calls the function that it has been passed
  // regularly. In this case with 80ms (8/100 seconds) between calls
  // For animations, it is better to use request animation frame
  setInterval(function() {
    
    // Do different things depending on the direction that the text
    // is spinning
    if (currentDirection == 0) {
      // Allow one complete rotation.
      if (currentAngle < 360) {
      
        // This line is what actually rotates the text.
        // It sets the css transform property to rotate the text.
        // Kind of like saying (in css)
        //   transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0.3, 90deg);
        myDIV.style.transform = "rotate3d(0,1,0.2," +
          currentAngle + "deg)";
          
          
        currentAngle += 10;
      } else {
        // Change the direction.
        currentDirection = 1;
        currentAngle -= 10;
        // It is repeated multiple times
        myDIV.style.transform = "rotate3d(0,1,0.2," +
          currentAngle + "deg)";
      }
    } else {
      // Allow one complete rotation.
      if (currentAngle > 0) {
        myDIV.style.transform = "rotate3d(0,1,0.2," +
          currentAngle + "deg)";
        currentAngle -= 10;
      } else {
        // Change the direction.
        currentDirection = 0;
        currentAngle += 10;
        myDIV.style.transform = "rotate3d(0,1,0.2," +
          currentAngle + "deg)";
      }
    }
  }, 80);
}
spin();
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <h1 id='myDIV'>my 3d text</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  var currentAngle = 0;
  var currentDirection = 0; // 0 - Increasing, 1 - Decreasing
  var STEP = 10;

  function spin() {
    document.getElementById("myDIV");
    setInterval(function() {
      if (currentDirection == 0) {
        // Allow one complete rotation.
        if (currentAngle < 360) {
          currentAngle += STEP;
        } else {
          // Change the direction.
          currentDirection = 1;
          currentAngle -= STEP;
        }
      } else {
        // Allow one complete rotation.
        if (currentAngle > 0) {
          currentAngle -= STEP;
        } else {
          // Change the direction.
          currentDirection = 0;
          currentAngle += STEP;
        }
      }

      console.log(currentDirection, currentAngle);

      myDIV.style.transform = `rotate3d(0, 1, 0.2, ${currentAngle}deg)`;
    }, 500);
  }

  spin();

</script>
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <h1 id='myDIV'>my 3d text</h1>
</div>
```

I updated your code for some understand.

Also, you can see the console.log from chrome developer mode.

## http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_3dtransforms.asp

Comment: Thankyou, I now understand the entire little program, except I don't understand this:  if(currentAngle > 0) { //why does this send the text one complete revolution anticlockwise??? I understand the first one if(currentAngle<360) that it sends it on a 360 spin clockwise.